# Escaping characters in fromJid when connecting to google talk from GAE via XMPP.

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

I have a chat application build on GAE. Internally chat messages between users are passed around via the google channel api. Since all the users already have google IDs, I'd like to also enable communication with users on google talk via XMPP.

To do this, I need to pass the user id (email) of the user initiating the chat on my end to google talk, so that when a message comes back, I can route it back to this user via his channel.

As such, I need to send the invitation, and subsequent messages with a fromUser JID

```
xmpp.sendInvitation(toUser, fromUser);
```

and the same fromUser JID for sending the message.

Reading through (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview), I see that Google supports two formats for the fromJID:

```
your_app_id@appspot.com
```

or,

```
anything@your_app_id.appspotchat.com
```

The first obviously won't work, but the second looks promising.

The issue is, I need to pass the full email address as the "anything" part, as that is the unique identifier (I can have jack@jill.com and jack@hill.com as users.)

So, I need to pass something along the lines of 
jack@jill.com@myapp.appspotchat.com

According to (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0106.html), I should be able to do this, and escape the @ character.

However, google doesn't seem to like it. I get a invalid JID exception if whether I escape the @ sign or not.

I've tried

```
email.replace("@", "\40");
```

and

```
email.replace("@", "\\\40");
```

I also noticed that in the google documentation I linked to above, it says,

> An app can also use a custom address in the following format, where anything is any string containing letters, numbers and hyphens

Does that mean they don't support escaped characters as per that extension? Or am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to escape them I'm missing?

There are a couple other routes I can take, but I can't get either of those to work either, so if anyone has suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it.

1. Passing the username as part of the node, and the domain as a resource. However, when I try this, I can send the invite and subsequent message with a full JID, such as jack@myapp.appspotchat.com/jill.com, but when the message comes back from google, the JID is stripped and comes back as a bare JID.
2. somehow maintain some metadata about the conversation, in essence maintaining session information for the chat that can be passed back and forth, but I'm not sure that's possible, and if it is, I haven't found any clues on how to make that work.

Comment: I'll look into this for you.  In the meantime, have you considered base64-encoding the email?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we only support letters, numbers, and hyphens as the docs suggest.  This even means that we don't accept *escaped* characters other than letters, numbers, and hyphens, even when XEP-0106 allows it.  This is more of an internal limitation of some of the systems upon which Google Talk is based than anything else.

That said, I'll work on making our docs a bit more explicit about this.